# Why import spaCy results in error in Python?

Tags: jupyter-lab

I'm trying to run:

```
!pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
!pip install -U spacy
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm #English model optimized for CPU
```

So when I try to run the cell below, it does not work. It keeps giving me an error whenever I run it.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

> ERROR: Invalid requirement: '#English'
>
> OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to
> be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

Comment: The error pretty much tells you the problem, spacy can't find the model file that was downloaded. This can be due to many reasons, are you sure you are running the correct virtual environment where you are importing spacy?